# How to show dates if no value present

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to construct a table with columns from Jan thru Dec and show the count of products that have been received per month YTD. Using data from Jan thru Jun as an example, data should populate in months Jan thru Jun and since no data is present for months July thru Dec, I would like for the value to be blank.

I have a 1 to Many relationship between my Date table and Products table. I've created a matrix table where I input the 'Month' field from the Date table into the Columns section and I get columns Jan thru Dec. Once I input the 'Product ID' field into the Values section and set it to count, since my Products table only has dates from Jan thru Jun, my matrix changes to only show months from Jan thru Jun.

I even tried a simple DAX function as shown below and my matrix still only shows months Jan thru Jun. **Does anyone know how I can show months with no data?**

Thank you.

```
Products Received = count(Products[Product ID])
```

[image: Matrix]

[image: Relationships]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure to allow the option **"Show items with no data"**, which should solve your issue as show in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Such an easy solution and yet I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: glad it helped , you can click on the checkmark below the upvote to accept as an answer if you feel this solved your issue! @EverythingZen